# How to add two integer values in Linux?

Tags: apt, bash

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /pg
file=`ls -l |awk '{print $9}'`
list=()
for i in $file
do
  echo $i
  a=`cat /pg/$i | head  -n  1 |awk '{print $8}'`
  b=`cat /pg/$i | head  -n  2 |awk '{print $8}'`
  #a1=`echo "$a" | tr -d  '"'`
  #b1=`echo "$b" | tr -d  '"'`
  echo $a
  echo $b
  c="$(($a+$b))"
  list=($c)
  #a1=`cat /pg/$i | head -n 2 |awk '{print $8}'`
done
```

While executing the above code i'm getting the below error please help me to fix the issue output of the values is `a=30` and `b=30` but still not able to add both.

```
/bin/max_timetrack.sh: line 16: 30+30
30: syntax error in expression (error token is "30")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're error is in this line:

```
b=`cat /pg/$i | head  -n  2 |awk '{print $8}'`
```

`head` won't give you the second line, but the *n* first lines.
So `b` will actually be:

```
30
30
```

and not `30` how you said.
Hence the error,

```
30+30
30
```

You would need (while keeping your complicated structure):

```
b=`cat /pg/$i | head  -n  2 |awk '{print $8}' | tail -n 1`
```

---

**However!**

There is a lot of useless/strange use of things in your little script:

This would be enough:

```
b=$(awk 'NR==2{print $8}' "/pg/$i")
```

Note the use of `$(...)` instead of backticks, which is the same [but to be preferred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449778/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-instead-of-backticks-in-shell-scripts).

Same with this line

```
a=`cat /pg/$i | head  -n  1 |awk '{print $8}'`
```

would better be

```
a=$(awk 'NR==1{print $8}' "/pg/$i")
```

---

Anyways, you can do the arithmetic inside `awk` only:

```
c=$(awk 'NR<=2{sum+=$8}END{print sum}')
```

Also you're [parsing `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead), which is a bad choice:

```
file=`ls -l | awk '{print $9}'`
```

Can't you just do this?

```
for i in *; do ... done
```

---

Depending on what you want to do with `c`, you can probably write the whole script as one `awk` command.

Comment: Thanks Mr.PLumo the above answer is working for me.